# Zurb Foundation 6 Increasing the size of offcanvas makes it visible while loading time

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Building a website with Zurb Foundation, I am using the off-canvas feature.

The default width of the off-canvas areas is 250px and I would like to increase it to, let's say, 600px.

Unfortunately, when I increase the width of the off-canvas, it becomes visible while loading...

Also, I noticed that when you expand or close the off-canvas, if it's bigger than 250px the "slide" works for 250px only.

Here's the HTML code to test:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/css/foundation.min.css">
    <style>
      #off-canvas-right {
        width: 600px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="off-canvas-left" data-off-canvas>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad cumque, eligendi. Deleniti rerum, distinctio tempora laboriosam velit incidunt hic asperiores officiis alias ea, sequi libero animi soluta totam, quia veritatis.
    </div>
    <div class="off-canvas position-right" id="off-canvas-right" data-off-canvas>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore voluptate velit, labore, voluptatem quia laborum temporibus asperiores at eos nulla nam ab fugit tenetur quaerat iusto architecto eum ea explicabo.
    </div>
    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
      <a data-open="off-canvas-left" class="text-center">Open left</a>
      <a data-open="off-canvas-right" class="text-center">Open right</a>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea that would help solve these 2 issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the CSS for transitioning in all states. I think this is also what's causing the jump in view on page load too. I believe that adding this to your styles will work:

```
#off-canvas-right {
  &.off-canvas {
    width: 600px;
    transform: translateX(600px);
    &.is-open {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a [link to a working CodePen](https://codepen.io/andyusdigital/pen/ROWOzB)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, it works like a charm :)